# Date filter in my Python dataFrame or in SQL query?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL query in Python with data of reservations. These reservations have a date.

I would like to make a filter where the user says which interval of dates are going to be in the dataframe.

For example, I would like to have the reservations from 01-01-22 to 01-03-22.

The problem is that I don't know how to create this filter, and whether it should be in Python or in my SQL query!

My DF looks basically like this:

| Date | Reservation ID | Route |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-22 | 35642 | LA-SD |
| 01-02-22 | 12432 | LA-SD |
| 01-03-22 | 55652 | LA-SD |
| 01-04-22 | 87642 | LA-SD |
| 01-05-22 | 97612 | LA-SD |
| 01-06-22 | 09731 | LA-SD |
| 01-06-22 | 25876 | LA-SD |
| 01-08-22 | 23775 | LA-SD |

Comment: For Python, [`DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)?

Comment: Use Postgres [Range type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) and do something like: `select '01/03/2022'::date <@ daterange('01-01-2022', '01-03-2022', '[]'); t` where range operators are explained here [Range operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html).

Comment: You can also use BETWEEN in a WHERE statement. For example: WHERE date BETWEEN '01-01-22 AND '01-03-22'
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

Answer (score 2):

I guess that your "Date" column is of type `text`. If so it has to be cast to type `date` first and then a simple query will do it all for you. Basically I think that data manipulation, filtering, aggregation etc. is much easier and better done with data tools, i.e. SQL.
Here it is:

```sql
select * from the_table 
where to_date("Date", 'mm-dd-yy') between '2022-01-01' and '2022-01-03';

-- Parameterized:
select * from the_table 
where to_date("Date", 'mm-dd-yy') between :period_start and :period_end;
```

Comment: this is the answer I wanted! Thanks